# Make a custom taxonomy appear in adding posts (like category)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing over a premium theme , I have some already registered taxonomies. Those taxonomies appears on the right side bar when creating custom posts (or custom pages not sure) that are related to the theme (and its plugins).

The thing is, such ability to choose from those taxonomies doesn't appear when creating 'normal' posts.  How can I make it appear there too?

What I've done so far is follow this [post](https://pippinsplugins.com/add-already-registered-taxonomy/), so I created a plugin and activated it. It have code like this

```
add_action('plugins_loaded','add_spTaxonomy_pt');
function add_spTaxonomy_pt(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('actual_taxonomy_name', 'post');
}

?>
```

But that didn't help. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wordpress Codex:

> Use register_taxonomy_for_object_type() right after the function to interconnect them. Else you could run into minetraps where the post type isn't attached inside filter callback that run during parse_request or pre_get_posts.

Is it possible to use an earlier hook maybe? The code looks alright otherwise.

Comment: as early as init :) Thank you.

Comment: Exactly :) No problem.